# Proof of $\lim\limits_{x‎\to‎ 0} \frac{e - (1+x)^\frac{1}{x}}{x}=\frac{e}{2}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

I want to prove $$\lim_{x‎\to‎ 0} \frac{e - (1+x)^\frac{1}{x}}{x}=\frac{e}{2}$$ without using L'Hôpital's rule, and Taylor Series.

Comment: i want dont use Taylor series  or [http://strg.xzn.ir/pictures/9_n.jpg]

Comment: I inderstand that. However, I asked what you DID try, not what you don't want to try.

Comment: If you do not want Taylor series, precise it in the post.

Comment: Maybe you should give a a list what is allowed, and why you do not want some standard methods.

Comment: i want proof this directly, likely proof of $\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=e$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

First, consider $A=(1+x)^\frac{1}{x}$. Take the logarithms of both sides so $$\log(A)=\frac{1}{x} \log(1+x)$$ Use the Taylor series of $\log(1+x)$; multiply the result by $\frac{1}{x}$; take the exponential; use the Taylor series and so on.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: then you get a messy $A$.

Comment: @8pir. Not at all. I think (but I can be wrong) that this is a very simple step-by-step method.

Comment: Taking the Taylor series when L'Hospital should not be used is... I don't know, it feels like cheating...

Comment: @5xum. Your point is interesting indeed ! So, I confess that I don't know !! But the OP did not write "without using derivatives", isn't ? Any suggestion from your side (I hate to feel that I could be cheating). Cheers and thanks :-)

Comment: yes, i want proof without using derivatives. i want proof this directly, likely proof of $\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=e$

Comment: You know that $\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=e$ but this is not sufficient for your problem. What you need is $(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=e + something$ and I do not see how you could get $something$ without using Taylor or derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

There is a direct proof but prepare, it is not going to be nice.
We are going to use the following well-known limits:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{e^x-1}{x}}=1$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{\ln{(x+1)}}{x}}=1$$ 
If you want a direct proof of them you can easily find it online.

Now let's go to the real deal; the limit you are asking for.

$$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{e-(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x}}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{e-e^{\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{x}}}{x}}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{e^{\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{x}}-e}{-x}}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{e(e^{\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{x}-1}-1)}{-x}}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{e(e^{\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{x}-1}-1)(\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{x}-1)}{-x(\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{x}-1)}}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{e(\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{x}-1)}{-x}}$$
$$=e\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{\frac{\ln{(1+x)}}{x}-1}{-x}}$$
$$=e\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{x-\ln{(1+x)}}{x^2}}$$
$$=\frac{e}{2}$$

Now let us show that

$$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{x-\ln{(1+x)}}{x^2}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{x-\ln{(1+x)}}{x^2}}$$
We substitute x=2x and get:
$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{2x-\ln{(1+2x)}}{4x^2}}$$
$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{2(x-\frac{1}{2}\ln{(1+2x))}}{4x^2}}$$
$$2L=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{x-\frac{1}{2}\ln{(1+2x)}}{x^2}}$$
Now lets substract the original limit $L$ from this new limit $2L$.

$$2L-L=L=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{x-\frac{1}{2}\ln{(1+2x)}-x+\ln{(1+x)}}{x^2}}$$
$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{\ln{(1+2x)}-2\ln{(1+x)}}{-2x^2}}$$
$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{\ln{(\frac{1+2x}{(1+x)^2})}}{-2x^2}}$$
$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{\ln{(1-\frac{x^2}{(1+x)^2})}}{-2x^2}}$$
$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{-x^2}{-2x^2(1+x^2)}}=\frac{1}{2}$$